# Updating UILabel text programmatically using a function

Tags: swift, uilabel

so I am trying to update the UIlabel text using a func. I have seen few other questions like mine and I tried their method but it doesn't work. fun returns no value when used in the UIlabel. I have shown my code below.It has to be noted that when I use the function in viewdidload I can retrieve the data.

```swift
lazy var name: UILabel = {
  let lb = UILabel()
  lb.text? = getthename()
  lb.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
  lb.textColor = .mainGreen
  lb.textAlignment = .left
  lb.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:12.0)
  return lb
}()

func getthename() -> String {
  var wins : String = ""
  let ud = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
  self.ref = Database.database().reference()
  self.ref.child("Users").child(ud!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
    if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
      wins = (getData["lastName "] as? String)!
    }
  })
  return wins
}
```

Comment: `if let getData = snapshot.value` could you add a print there, and a print when you do `return wins`? Which one do you think is printed first, which one is really printed first? You are missing the asynchrone logic/concept.

Comment: when I print it in the view did load it does print it correctly. when I use it in UILabel It doesnt return anything

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked you to replace `if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {` with `print("Something1"); if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {` and `return wins` with `print("Somethin2"); return wins`, and ask you, in your opinion which print (Something1 or Something2) should appear in console first, and in reality which ones appear first.

Comment: not sure if this is what you said: func getthename()  {
        var wins : String = ""
        let ud = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        self.ref.child("Users").child(ud!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            print("Something1")

        })
        print("Somethin2")

    }

Comment: I tried this and from viewdidload when I call the function I get this :
Somethin2
()
Something1

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PgzY2Upb Which print that I added you think will be shown first in console? Which print that I added will be in reality print first in console? I'm not trying to solve your issue by giving the answer, I'm trying to show you what is the concept you are missing: "Asynchronous". It's a basic and important need to know.

Comment: something2 comes first but I dunno why

Comment: Finally, you pointed out the issue. Just before it was "it's not working", now you'll see that it's returned string is indeed empty when read. Because your method is asynchrone. Look for "Swift + Asynchrone + Closure" to manage that.

Comment: @Larme do I have to add a line for closure/completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this line of code

`lb.text? = getthename()`

With `lb.text = getthename()`

You're currently using optional unwrapping by using the "?" symbol and it is causing that line to essentially equate to `nil = getthename()`

Also, as mentioned by @Larme the following code is actually asynchronous:

```
self.ref.child("Users").child(ud!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
    if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
      wins = (getData["lastName "] as? String)!
    }
  })
```

Rather than trying to set your label's text within the lazy variable initializer I would recommend you set it elsewhere. You can update the `getthename()` function to use a reference to the label to update the label's text after the call to `observeSingleEvent()` has returned.

So something like this

```
lazy var name: UILabel = {
  let lb = UILabel()
  lb.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
  lb.textColor = .mainGreen
  lb.textAlignment = .left
  lb.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:12.0)
  return lb
}()
```

Then the `getthename()` function can be changed to the following. You can call the function from anywhere and it will set the label for you.

```
func getthename() {
  var wins : String = ""
  let ud = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
  self.ref = Database.database().reference()
  self.ref.child("Users").child(ud!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
    if let getData = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
      self?.name.text = (getData["lastName "] as? String)!
    }
  })
}
```

Please notice the `[weak self]` in the `observeSingleEvent()` closure as with any asynchronous code you need to check to make sure whether the right variables are still available.